# Is there an elevator pitch for the SE Network?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-promotion

I meet a lot of people regularly who have the knowledge and interest to participate in various SE communities however, many a time they do not know of SE, or of the existence of any site beyond Stack Overflow.

[image]

So, in such cases, what would be a good [elevator pitch](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/) that would make them log on to Stack Exchange and explore the Network?

Comment: To some extent the first lines on each site's About page could count. Though they are perhaps not all that catchy.

Comment: If they haven't found SO by googling a coding issue, then either they never have coding issues (either a very good or very bad thing), or they don't know how to google (because every time I search a coding issue, SO is in the first couple links). If it's the second thing, you should just recommend google and they'll organically find SO. And if it's the first thing, SO won't help them.

Comment: Oh, wait... SE, not SO... I sometimes forget that there are non-coding related sites on this network. Nevermind!

Comment: Elevator goatse.

Answer (score 4):

Currently for users with less than 200 reputation on each question page there is a big advertisement, sized 728x90 pixels. Example:

> [image]

Major part of those ads are for the Careers site and rarely there is a paying sponsor.

I suggest to push Stack Exchange there, only for <200 rep users, something like this:

> [image]

It can also feature specific sites, e.g. based on the logged in user tags.

Comment: *"I suggest to push Stack Exchange there"* ... for <200 rep users?

Comment: @Bart yes, just one ad among many others, not something that will stick always. Right now 9 out of 10 showing ads for Careers, so I think 1 out of 10 promoting Stack Exchange itself is fair.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I assumed for a moment you were saying "and if above 200, we can use the space for the SE add".

Comment: @Bart trying to make it more clear now. :)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP's question. "I meet people who don't know about SE sites at all" -> "SE sites need banner ads for other SE sites that the people you meet will never see".

Comment: @Wooble *"or of the existence of any site beyond Stack Overflow"* ...

Comment: @Wooble as far as I understand, the issue here is Stack Overflow users who are oblivious that it's part of a wider network.

Answer (score 3):

Tired of all the noise and nonsense you see when trying to get a question answered in an online forum?

You should check out Stack Exchange sites instead. They've solved that problem by putting the focus where it belongs—on the questions and the answers. Answers have to…well…*answer the question*, or they get removed. There's no noise, and it's easy to find what you're looking for.

Plus, it's where the experts hang out, so the help you get is always top-notch.

It's always free, so check it out! I'm pretty sure you'll <strike>like</strike> love it!

---

<sup>(Modify as necessary, depending on the length of your elevator ride and/or your ability to be peppy.)</sup>

Comment: This sounds like an infomercial. You need to add some Billy Mays style words and exclamations.

Comment: Fair enough. I have more experience watching infomercials than I do creepy elevator encounters.

Comment: Better make that a CW to avoid situations like [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17030) - looks like spam on first, second and third glance.

Comment: Hmm. I might have rejected that, too. This was actually intended to be a serious attempt at an elevator-style pitch. Not an all out funny-but-not-so-useful infomercial. @Cole can post that as a separate answer, CW if he wants.

Answer (score 1):

For formal situations you could use something like this:

> Stack Exchange is a growing network of individual communities, each
> dedicated to serving experts in a specific field. We build libraries
> of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's
> area of expertise.
>
> From programmers sharing answers on parsing HTML, to researchers
> seeking solutions to combinatorial problems, to photographers exposing
> lighting techniques, our communities are built by and for those best
> able to define them: the experts and enthusiasts.

-From the [Stack Exchange About Page](https://stackexchange.com/about)

For informal situations:

Stack Exchange kicks ---*!
<sup>*this expletive removed for reasons of moderation</sup>